# Render HTML inside block - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to render a HTML with a partial inside of a block but the only thing that renders are the last 4 closing `</div>` elements.

Here is my code:

```
<%= new_item_modal do |i| %>
<div class="modal fade" id="newItemModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newItemModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">New Item</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="new-item" style="overflow:scroll;height:500px;">
        <%= render partial: "/items/form", locals: { remote: true, item: @item, categories: @categories }%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And my `new_item_modal` function:

```
def new_item_modal(&block)
   if current_location.present? && can_access("create", "items")
      @item = Item.new
      @categories = current_location.categories
      block.call
   end  
end
```

Comment: I don't see where you close the block.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah I accidentally left out that line in the question. Adding it in now.

Comment: This looks like something `link_to` does (and other helpers as well). You can get some ideas from its implementation: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ee21e058424b2cb55bf74981c28b1ac0fb98b576/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L196-L206

Comment: I would suggest you to use relative path `'items/form'` instead of `'/items/form'` as the path that points to the partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line should read `<%= new_item_modal do |item, categories| %>` and your `new_modal_item` method should have `block.call(@item, @categories)`. Make sure you rename the variables passed to the partial (for example, from `@item` to `item`).